# ASP.Net Core 3.0 Windows Authentication with Custom Role Based Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, authorization, windows-authentication

I'm looking to use Windows Authentication in an ASP.NET 3.0 MVC app with roles I pull from a SQL database for API security.  I will decorate the API controller methods with something like `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`

A lot of what I have here, I've picked up from this site, but I'm stuck on the last part. 
I can see that the role is applied to the user, but can't get the authorization to work.

To do this, I first start with a ClaimsTransformer, which will be used to apply roles through claims to my users.

**ClaimsTransformer.cs**

```
    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        //This sample will automatically apply the Admin role to the user
        //In the real app, I will check the user against my DB and apply all roles (as claims) here
        var ci = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
        var c = new Claim(ci.RoleClaimType, "Admin");
        ci.AddClaim(c);

        return await Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
```

**Startup.cs - ConfigureServices**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        //Register the ClaimsTransformer here
        services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();

        //Use windows authentication
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.AddAuthorization();
    }
```

**Starup.cs - Configure**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

**DataController.cs**

In the API controller, I can set up a method with no authorization like this and see the result showing true when I check if User.IsInRole("Admin");

```
    [HttpGet]   
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetData1()
    {
        var result = User.IsInRole("Admin");

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

However, if I decorate the controller method with `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` like this, then I get a Forbidden response on calls to this method.

```
    [HttpGet]       
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetData1()
    {
        var result = User.IsInRole("Admin");

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use Policy Based authorization and the authorization service? Take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies). It's more advanced than roles.

Comment: Also note that the order is `UseAuthentication` (who is the user) and then `UseAuthorization` (what is the user allowed to do). That explains why authorization doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, hell yes!  The UseAuthorization, UseAuthentication order was the problem.
Thanks a lot.  If you put up the answer I can give you credit.
To answer your first response, I looked into policy as well.  That didn't work for the same reason (the order).  I'm migrating from a role based system so, just matching what I had, but I am aware I can expand.  Thanks again.

Comment: I Didn't know if you were aware, that's why I mentioned it. Glad I could help and thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case it's a small but common mistake of switching lines, [the order](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/#order) is `UseAuthentication` (who is the user) and then `UseAuthorization` (what is the user allowed to do). That explains why authorization doesn't work.